# Как подключить виртуальную клавиатуру на Андроид при написании приложения?

Tags: android

Пишу первое приложение, хочу сделать возможность сохранения результата с подписью (как в старых аркадных играх) - можно конечно самому создать это виртуальную клавиатуру, но хочется верить, что есть готовая реализация данной возможности, но я никак не могу найти не то что примера, а названия, либо ссылки на статью об этом.

Comment: Как только EditText получает фокус, клавиатура вызывается автоматически.

Comment: За ранее извиняюсь, совсем недавно осваиваю... Уточняю - пишу простую игру на андроид, используя libgdx, EditText, как я понимаю там не используется, но я нашёл класс TextField, вроде он для этого, но ни одного примера использования я не нашел, а инициализация по документации вылетает на строке установке цвета...

Answer (score 1):

Всё, разобрался..
Gdx.input.setOnscreenKeyboardVisible(true); 
Всё было гораздо проще...  Правда так и не понял,  почему TextField не работал, но можно и без этого класса обойтись.